# Getting an IP Allocation from ARIN

Tags: ip

The datacenter I am looking to Colo with is being very stingy about IP addresses, only giving me 8 for a quarter rack. I need like 40 and am planning to need a lot more. I saw on the Arin site that I could get about 4k ipv4 for about $1250, is that a total cost or is that annually. Also once I have the IP address allocation what do I do with it, i hear i need a bgp router, would the data center have one, is this something I would need? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind describing (generally) why you need 40 IPs within a quarter rack?

Comment: IPv4 addresses are running out, so the price will go up dramatically in the near future. I would consider architectural changes to reduce IP address usage. If you're doing SSL hosting, you might be stuck, but certificates with alternative principal names can reduce your IP usage by a huge amount.

Comment: We are a hosting company with many VMs and we give each client their own ip associated with their VM.

Comment: "The datacenter I am looking to Colo with is being very stingy about IP addresses." Pick a different colo?

Comment: @embobo Perhaps the ipcalypse/arpageddon started early?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARIN is [pretty strict about their allocations](https://www.arin.net/policy/nrpm.html), especially in recent years. Unless you can demonstrate a need for a /20 or a /22 they all but require you to get your addresses from an upstream provider. You might have an easier time buying additional IPs from your hosting provider. If they won't or can't give you additional addresses then that's probably a good indication that you should look for a different provider.